# Trying to use inline conditional PHP on a WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I am trying to tell my WordPress template to use a specific open graph image if it's currently on the home page. WordPress has a built-in function to determine if you are currently on the homepage:

```
is_front_page().
```

My template had this in the header.php:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url('mint-full-post'); ?>" />
```

And I changed it to this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php is_front_page() ? echo 'http://rainydaystories.com/wp-content/uploads/social.jpg' : echo the_post_thumbnail_url('mint-full-post'); ?>" />
```

This causes the site to crash. What am I doing wrong, and can anyone help me find a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Tip: you can also use is_home().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the ternary operator wrong, it should be like this:

```
<?php echo (is_front_page()) ? 'http://rainydaystories.com/wp-content/uploads/social.jpg' : the_post_thumbnail_url('mint-full-post'); ?>
```

You can also use short tags like this:

The `<?=` part is the same as `<?php echo`,

However, short tags are disabled in PHP versions older than 5.4.0 and enabled by default in 5.4.0 and above

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks. So the echo command can't come after the ?

Comment: No, for more details check the [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), if this answer solves your question feel free to approve it.